# Filtering string data in a DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, search, datagrid

I've got a DataGrid that has a single column of string data.  The ItemsSource of the datagrid is a DataSet.

I want to filter this via textbox in real time.  I've come up with this, mostly as a proof of concept.  UsersSearchChanged is just the even that fires when the textbox text changes:

```
    private void UsersSearchChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            SearchForUser(SearchUsersTextBox.Text);
    }


    private void SearchForUser(string searchTerm)
    {
        var myData = usersData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new
        {
            column1 = r.Field<string>("UserName")
        });

        var list = myData.ToList();

        var filtered = list.Where(name => name.column1.StartsWith(searchTerm));

        usersDataGrid.ItemsSource = filtered;
    }
```

This doesn't quite work though and returns the error:

```
"BindingExpression path error: 'UserName' property not found on 'object'..."
```

I'm not sure I'm even approaching this problem correctly and am a bit lost in how to proceed.  The goal here is a 'live' search of a list of users that responds to every keystroke in a textbox.

Comment: I'm gonna guess in your XAML template you have the propterty *UserName* defined in the template for the usersDataGrid?. You do realise that the list you assign conatins anonymous objects with a *Column1* property instead of UserName - why are you even doing a select projection?

Comment: Well your error is kind of leading you in the right direction.  That section assigning 'myData' looks like you don't have a field of 'UserName'.  I would chop it up smaller to start.  Ensure that you have a dataTable in usersData that has that column.  You could always do the cheapy .Select(r => r[0]) to just get the first column too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already mentioned a comment but I think you can break things apart easier to see what they contain.  Generally something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        d.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(int));
        d.Columns.Add("MinValue", typeof(float));
        d.Columns.Add("MaxValue", typeof(float));

        d.Rows.Add(1, 0.1, 0.2);
        d.Rows.Add(1, 0.2, 0.4);
        d.Rows.Add(1, 0.1, 0.2);

        var dataTable = d.AsEnumerable();
        var data = dataTable.Select(x => x[0]).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine($"{data.Count}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If I was not sure what columns I had I could add a breakpoint after 'dataTable' was assigned and see what it had for debugging.  I prefer most times to stay away from DataTables and favor POCOs over them with C# after 3.5 and the introduction of Linq.  Mixing Linq with DataTables and collections is just messy.  Better to have well formed objects for specific listing of properties, else you are doing the ('stringName') where you could get something wrong.  When you have something like

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

anytime you select from Foo it would be like .Select(x => x.Bar) which is far simpler to work with.